# How do you get the location, in x-y coordinate pixels, of a mouse click?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse

In C++ (WIN32), how can I get the (X,y) coordinate of a mouse click on the screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the plain Win32 API, use this in your handler for [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because it tells you where the mouse *was* when the user clicked, instead of where it *is* when you process the message (it might have moved).

Answer (score 1):

You can call [GetMouseMovePointsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646259(VS.85).aspx) to get the mouse position and history. Alternatively, if you have access to your wndproc, you can just check the lparam of [WM_MOUSEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645616(VS.85).aspx), [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607(VS.85).aspx) or similar message for the x,y coordinates.

Comment: Will this work when DPI scaling is done in windows 7, or windows 10. For example if initial DPI scaling value is 150%, and then we set it to 100%, will this method still work? I am facing an issue in an application, that this isn't working. Everything works fine when I log-out, and log-in again.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++:

[GetCursorPos](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390.aspx)

[System::Windows::Forms::Control::MousePosition](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition%28VS.71%29.aspx)

[System::Windows::Forms::Cursor:: Position](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx)

C++:

[Mouse Position](http://www.codemiles.com/c-c/mouse-position-in-c-t669.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
bool find(xPos,yPos);
```

Now you will get the x and y position of the mouse pointer in the coordinate. xPos and yPos should be long:

```
bool find(long x,long y);
```

Inside, check if xPos and yPos come under any object in the screen coordinate.

Answer (score -1):

```
POINT p; //You can use this to store the values of x and y coordinates
```

Now assuming you will handle this on clicking the left mouse button

```
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        p.x = LOWORD(lParam); //X coordinate
        p.y = HIWORD(lParam); //Y coordinate
        /* the rest of your code */
        break;
```

Comment: Remarks from MSDN WM_LBUTTONDOWN: Do not use the LOWORD or HIWORD macros to extract the x- and y- coordinates of the cursor position because these macros return incorrect results on systems with multiple monitors. Systems with multiple monitors can have negative x- and y- coordinates, and LOWORD and HIWORD treat the coordinates as unsigned quantities.

Comment: @user2120666 i didn't know that, it's still used in some examples on MSDN (i.e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )